# Print and bind manpages

Tags: man

I intend to print and bind all the manpages for my distribution. For actually retrieving all the manpages, I found I can use rpm2cpio to get all the manpages, but I don't know to retain the formatting on the manpages or know a way to get all of them in one place. I also might need to be able to change margins, but I can worry about that later.

Things I've tried:

- Downloading everything from linux.die.net then converting to a pdf
- man manpage > file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention `rpm2cpio`, I’ll assume you’re using a Linux distribution; on those, you can produce printer-ready versions of manpages using the following command:

```
man -Tps ls > ls.ps
```

The resulting `ls.ps` file contains the `ls` manpage in PostScript format:

[image: Screenshot of the top of the formatted ls manpage]

Note that printing *all* the manpages in your distribution will result in an enormous book. This used to be a somewhat popular activity a couple of decades ago, and one could buy books containing all the manpages. I still have the Coherent manual which is mostly such a print-out.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Yes, actually when I was looking for a book like this, I found an old RH and a FreeBSD book with selected manpages.